# SVN commit batch

Tags: svn

I know there is a command that updates the changes like

```
c:\svn up <working directory>
```

i wonder if there is any command line statement which can commit the changes.

..: Any help would be appreciated :..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cd <working directory>    
svn commit -m "your comment"
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to consulting the [SVN documentation](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/), you can also run

```
svn help
```

for a list of all the commands.  Then you can get specific help by running

```
svn help commit
```

for example.

Answer (score 1):

C:> SVN commit  (your path here)

would do the trick

you might want to use the [Svn red book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/re06.html)

Answer (score 0):

By default, [check in/commit](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.ref.svn.c.commit.html) will commit **all** changed files:

```
$ svn ci -m "Finally fixed the bug that caused the printer to erupt into flames"
```

Comment: This is nice. But i don't where i can write this script? Can i write it inside .bat file?